# Why didn't Anakin just leave the Jedi Order?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, revenge-of-the-sith, attack-of-the-clones

Anakin got Padame pregnant. I understand that Anakin had to keep the pregnancy a secret, or he would be kicked out of the Jedi but why could he not just peacefully leave the Jedi and do something else? He loved his girlfriend/wife so much what is the point in continuing such a dangerous job as a Jedi, whilst breaking the rules?

Comment: Note that marriage ***isn't*** fine. It's also strictly forbidden by the Jedi code.

Comment: It's against the rules for precisely the reason described by Yoda. ["The fear of loss is a path to the dark side".](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZXekWMcCrLM&feature=youtu.be&t=32). "Attachment leads to jealousy.", etc.

Comment: Okay that helps to clarify. I still do not understand why he did not just leave either officially by telling them, or unofficially by just running away.

Comment: There's also the fact that she's broken the law by not getting permission from her Queen before embarking on this relationship.

Comment: Well, there was a war going on...not the best environment to raise a family.

Comment: Anakin is being manipulated by Darth Sidious to turn him to the dark side. Sidious doesn't want him leaving the Jedi and heading off to another world so keeps him close by playing on his love for Padme (and fears about her safety). He also needs Anakin to turn against the Jedi and help him destroy them from within, which he can't do if he if he's not a part of the order.

Comment: ^ I think he was aware of her pregnancy before he spoke to Sidious, so he could have vanished long before?

Comment: @securityauditor - unlikely, Anakin has been a Jedi padawan since he was a child and it has been known since he was found that he has an extraordinarily high force potential. Sidious has been manipulating the Jedi since before Anakin was found and these manipulations are not always verbal e.g. IIRC it's heavily implied that the dreams Anakin has about Padme dying are triggered by Sidious to manipulate him.

Answer (score 12):

#### Anakin wants to save Padme

The Force is not Jedi/Sith exclusive. Anakin would still be Force sensitive, even if he somehow resigned from the Jedi Order. And he had lot of skills (piloting, engineering ) even if he had to put his lightsaber away. Also, Padme was not exactly penniless :)

But, there was another problem - his visions about Padme's death. His fear that he will lose her (just like he lost his mother) made him search for more power and knowledge about the Force. The primary reason he wanted to become a Jedi Master (and major disappointment when he was refused) was to have access to Jedi Archives with forbidden knowledge only Masters were allowed to study. He hoped he would find information there about the ways to cheat death.

Therefore, he was an easy prey for Sidious when he offered exactly the knowledge that the Jedi Order denied. Sidious purposely put him close to Padme in Episode 2, sensing his attraction to her and counting on her to become his greatest weakness. Throughout the Clone Wars she was his unwilling pawn to twist Anakin to Dark Side.

Answer (score 6):

**He doesn't have anywhere else to go.**

Anakin's mother dies in Ep. 2, and he is essentially left with no one on his home planet of Tatooine that he knows well and *likes*. He also has the memory of being a slave there, and the embarrassing incident with the Sand People that he later confides to Palpatine. Perhaps he could go try to live on the Lars' farm, but that is possibly the one place he would never want to return to.

**He doesn't have any real job skills.**

Anakin went from slavery straight into Jedi Training (TM). Other than moving stuff around with the Force, he doesn't seem to have many skills that *would* translate well to a civilian career. The Republic (unlike Star Trek's Federation) is *not* a post-scarcity society - they have social problems galore, serious poverty, and major inequalities. One can't just "float around" and depend on a social safety net. People who try that get *killed*, thrown into a Rancor pit, or starve.

We see this sort of job skills problem in our own world - the stereotypical "homeless veteran" who gets out of the military with plenty of combat skills, but without the skills necessary to "make it" in the civilian world. Anakin has literally been with the Jedi since he was *nine years old*, way younger than the age that most people enter the military in our own world, meaning that his skills, contacts, etc. are even lower than one might expect for someone who joined a military force as an adult.

It's true that he's a good pilot, but he's impulsive and insubordinate - perhaps OK for the kinds of missions that the Jedi go on, but exactly the kind of pilot that would *not* be wanted for regular cargo missions or even smuggling.

Comment: He could build droids and podracers out of scrap when he was a child, I'd say he has some marketable skills there. As for learning to function outside the Jedi temple, I'm sure Padme could help him out. I imagine senators wages weren't small either.

Comment: Anakin could have easily gotten a mercenary or body guard job. On top of that his baby mama is a Senator. I'm sure with their combined connections Anakin could find a job that would use his extremely exceptional military skills.

Comment: ^ Exactly my points, he had options.

Answer (score 0):

While the other answers are legitimate, I believe there is another answer. The fact that he thought Padme would die kept him in the order, where he was 100% sure he could speak to Palpatine as a Jedi. Therefore, for fear of losing Padme, he stayed in the order.

Comment: You're wrong and you're right. He was hoping to gain access to the Jedi archive (available only to Masters). That's also why he was so grumpy about being denied the rank of Master